# Eloquent/Laravel: is there a counterpart to object->load('relation'), eg. object->unload('relation')?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When i update a relation, e.g. update parent_id on Child (Child belongsTo Parent, Parent hasMany Child) and respond with the Child->Parent object, somehow the returned Parent is still the old one. I think this is because the Parent is already loaded at that time.

I now want to *unlaod* the relations so the new Parent is fetched from db again.

Is there a way to *unload* the loaded relationships? Like you can lazy-load by using model->load('relation'), can you also unload it again?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What if you just call `load('relation')` again?

Comment: @lukasgeiter This is exactly the way to reload the relation from db.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can unload relations by unsetting the magic property (at least in Laravel 5.3 and up).

Usage:

```
unset($model->relation);
```

What makes this work (from the Model class):

```
public function __unset($key)
{
    unset($this->attributes[$key], $this->relations[$key]);
}
```

It does the same as `$model->setRelations([])`, but for a specific relation (instead of unloading all relations).

Answer (score 18):

Unloading relations can be done by passing an empty array to the model

```
$child->setRelations([]);
```

when you call a relation on the model after that, it will be reloaded at that moment.

.. in the current version (5.x) at least, maybe not at the time of your question :)

Answer (score 11):

As of Laravel 5.6, there is an `unsetRelation(string)` function.

```
$parent->load('child');

$parent->unsetRelation('child');
```

I think this provides a little more readability if you're just trying to unset a single relationship, rather than removing all by `$parent->setRelationships([])`.

Answer (score 4):

*There is no counterpart to `load` that would allow to unload a relationship.*

However, to reload a relation from the database you can just call `load` again

```
$parent = $child->load('relation');
// change parent_id
$parent = $child->load('relation');
```

I've quickly looked at the source of laravel and found no hint of some kind of caching. So it just performs a new query fetching the relationship again.

Thanks @Jarek Tkaczyk for confirming my assumption

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution! Still, is there an option to unload a relation once loaded?

Comment: Puh not that I would know of... Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I'm looking for a more general solution as i have a controller serving many different models and it's not aware of which changes were made to each model, so i would basically unload all relations before responding to a PUT. Also, i'm just curious… Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you please add a statement to your answer saying that there is no counterpart so i can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: I was looking for this sort of thing. I have an API that creates a model and then returns the created object (some of the fields are calculated based on the original input). I do not need the API method to return the object with _all_ of it's relations as the API call would be slower. Interestingly, I didn't explicitly load any relationships but a ``belongsTo`` relationship is being loaded anyways.

Comment: @Vic To really help you I would need to see your code. Please open a new question. If you want to, you can leave me a link here an I will take a look at it...

Comment: @lukasgeiter Sorry, I wasn't really posting a question. I was just commenting that maybe Laravel _should_ have a way to unload a relation and provided a use case. I realized that I _was_ loading the relation by trying to access an attribute of the related object. Thanks though! :D